# Trying to solve an MFC BEGIN_EVENT_MAP Compile-time error

Tags: c++, mfc

I am converting a VC++6.0 project to Visual Studio 2013. I am encountering this error:

```
error C2440: cannot convert from const AFX_EVENTMAP *(__thiscall CCmdTargetEx::* )(void) const' to 'const AFX_EVENTMAP *(__stdcall *)(void)'
```

here is my code

```
BEGIN_EVENT_MAP(CDispatchAccount, CCmdTargetEx) //error locate in here
//{{AFX_EVENT_MAP(CDispatchAccount)
EVENT_CUSTOM( "SetFocus",       FireSetFocus,       VTS_NONE )
EVENT_CUSTOM( "KillFocus",      FireKillFocus,      VTS_NONE )
EVENT_CUSTOM( "Tab",            FireTab,            VTS_NONE )
EVENT_CUSTOM( "EditFull",       FireEditFull,       VTS_NONE )
EVENT_CUSTOM( "EditEnter",      FireEditEnter,      VTS_NONE )
EVENT_CUSTOM( "ListSelChanged", FireListSelChanged, VTS_I2   )
EVENT_CUSTOM( "ChangeAccount",  FireChangeAccount,  VTS_NONE )
EVENT_CUSTOM( "DropDown",       FireDropDown,       VTS_I2   )
EVENT_CUSTOM( "MSRReceived",    FireMSRReceived,    VTS_BSTR VTS_BOOL VTS_PVARIANT)
EVENT_CUSTOM( "EmplEditFull",   FireEmplEditFull,   VTS_NONE )
//}}AFX_EVENT_MAP 
END_EVENT_MAP()
```

and this is my header

```
#ifdef  __BASECLASS_DLL
   #define  __CMDTARGET_API __declspec(dllexport)
#elif _FORMMNGR_DLL
   #define  __CMDTARGET_API 
#elif _DATAMNGR_DLL
    #define __CMDTARGET_API
#elif _CONTROL_DLL  
    #define __CMDTARGET_API __declspec(dllimport)
#else
    #define __CMDTARGET_API
#endif  // __BASECLASS_DLL


class __CMDTARGET_API CCmdTargetEx : public CCmdTarget
{
   DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CCmdTargetEx)

   public:
          CCmdTargetEx();           // protected constructor used by dynamic 
   creation
          virtual ~CCmdTargetEx();

   // Attributes
    protected:
           const IID    *m_piidEvents;  // IID for control events
           const IID    *m_piidPrimary; // IID for primary idispatch
           DWORD        m_dwEventSink;
           CWnd        *m_pContainer;
           UINT         m_nCtrlID;

   // Operations
   public:
          void      AFX_CDECL FireEvent(DISPID dispid, BYTE* pbParams, ...);
          BOOL      GetDispatchIID(IID *pIID);
          virtual   HRESULT GetClassID(LPCLSID pclsid);
          void      ConnectSinkSelf(CWnd *pContainer, UINT nCtlID=-1);
          void      DisconnectSinkSelf();

  // Overrides
 // ClassWizard generated virtual function overrides
 //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(CCmdTargetEx)
   public:
         virtual void OnFinalRelease();
//}}AFX_VIRTUAL

// Implementation
protected:

BOOL    OnEvent(AFX_EVENT* pEvent);

// Events
virtual const AFX_EVENTMAP *GetEventMap() const;
virtual const AFX_EVENTMAP *GetThisEventMap() const;
static const AFX_DATA AFX_EVENTMAP_ENTRY _eventEntries[];
static const AFX_DATA AFX_EVENTMAP eventMap;
const AFX_EVENTMAP_ENTRY *GetEventMapEntry(LPCTSTR pszName, DISPID *pDispid) const;
void FireEventV(DISPID dispid, BYTE *pbParams, va_list argList);

// Generated message map functions
//{{AFX_MSG(CCmdTargetEx)
    // NOTE - the ClassWizard will add and remove member functions here.
//}}AFX_MSG

DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
// Generated OLE dispatch map functions
//{{AFX_DISPATCH(CCmdTargetEx)
    // NOTE - the ClassWizard will add and remove member functions here.
//}}AFX_DISPATCH
DECLARE_DISPATCH_MAP()
DECLARE_INTERFACE_MAP()

// Connection point container
virtual LPCONNECTIONPOINT GetConnectionHook(REFIID iid);
virtual BOOL GetExtraConnectionPoints(CPtrArray *pConnPoints);

// Connection point for events - from COleControl
BEGIN_CONNECTION_PART(CCmdTargetEx, EventConnPt)
    virtual void OnAdvise(BOOL bAdvise);
    virtual REFIID GetIID();
    virtual LPUNKNOWN QuerySinkInterface(LPUNKNOWN pUnkSink);
END_CONNECTION_PART(EventConnPt)

BEGIN_INTERFACE_PART(EventSink, IDispatch)
    INIT_INTERFACE_PART(COleControlSite, EventSink)
    STDMETHOD(GetTypeInfoCount)(unsigned int*);
    STDMETHOD(GetTypeInfo)(unsigned int, LCID, ITypeInfo**);
    STDMETHOD(GetIDsOfNames)(REFIID, LPOLESTR*, unsigned int, LCID, DISPID*);
    STDMETHOD(Invoke)(DISPID, REFIID, LCID, unsigned short, DISPPARAMS*,
                      VARIANT*, EXCEPINFO*, unsigned int*);
END_INTERFACE_PART(EventSink)

// IProvideClassInfo2
BEGIN_INTERFACE_PART(ProvideClassInfo, IProvideClassInfo2)
    INIT_INTERFACE_PART(COleControl, ProvideClassInfo)
    STDMETHOD(GetClassInfo)(LPTYPEINFO *ppTypeInfo);
    STDMETHOD(GetGUID)(DWORD dwGuidKind, GUID *pGUID);
END_INTERFACE_PART(ProvideClassInfo)
};
```

And this declaration `CDispatchAccount`

```
class CCtlAccount;
class CDispatchAccount : public CCmdTargetEx
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE( CDispatchAccount )
    DECLARE_OLETYPELIB( CDispatchAccount ) 

public:
    CDispatchAccount();           // protected constructor used by dynamic creation

// Attributes
public:
    CCtlAccount*        m_pConnObj;

// Operations
public:
    void    SetConnObject   ( CCtlAccount* pConnObj ) { m_pConnObj = pConnObj; }
    HRESULT GetClassID      ( LPCLSID pclsid );


// Overrides
    // ClassWizard generated virtual function overrides
    //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(CDispatchAccount)
    public:
    virtual void OnFinalRelease();
    //}}AFX_VIRTUAL

// Implementation
protected:
    virtual ~CDispatchAccount();

    // Generated message map functions
    //{{AFX_MSG(CDispatchAccount)
        // NOTE - the ClassWizard will add and remove member functions here.
    //}}AFX_MSG

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    // Generated OLE dispatch map functions
    //{{AFX_DISPATCH(CDispatchAccount)
    afx_msg BOOL GetBranchCodeHide();
    afx_msg void SetBranchCodeHide(BOOL nNewValue);
    afx_msg short GetBorder();
    afx_msg void SetBorder(short nNewValue);
    afx_msg BOOL GetBranchCodeAuto();
    afx_msg void SetBranchCodeAuto(BOOL nNewValue);
    afx_msg BSTR GetItemCodeDefault();
    afx_msg void SetItemCodeDefault(LPCTSTR lpszNewValue);
    afx_msg short GetInputDevice();
    afx_msg void SetInputDevice(short nNewValue);
    afx_msg long GetItemCodeType();
    afx_msg void SetItemCodeType(long nNewValue);
    afx_msg BSTR GetAccNameCtl();
    afx_msg void SetAccNameCtl(LPCTSTR lpszNewValue);
    afx_msg BSTR GetAccPwdCtl();
    afx_msg void SetAccPwdCtl(LPCTSTR lpszNewValue);
    afx_msg BOOL GetAddTrustAccount();
    afx_msg void SetAddTrustAccount(BOOL nNewValue);
    afx_msg BOOL GetAutoNextFocus();
    afx_msg void SetAutoNextFocus(BOOL nNewValue);
    afx_msg BOOL GetUseHistory();
    afx_msg void SetUseHistory(BOOL nNewValue);
    afx_msg BOOL GetRequireInput();
    afx_msg void SetRequireInput(BOOL nNewValue);
    afx_msg long GetHeight();
    afx_msg void SetHeight(long nNewValue);
    afx_msg long GetWidth();
    afx_msg void SetWidth(long nNewValue);
    afx_msg BOOL GetEnabled();
    afx_msg void SetEnabled(BOOL bNewValue);
    afx_msg BSTR GetCaption();
    afx_msg void SetCaption(LPCTSTR lpszNewValue);
    afx_msg OLE_COLOR GetBackColor();
    afx_msg void SetBackColor(OLE_COLOR nNewValue);
    afx_msg OLE_COLOR GetForeColor();
    afx_msg void SetForeColor(OLE_COLOR nNewValue);
    afx_msg BOOL GetVisible();
    afx_msg void SetVisible(BOOL bNewValue);
    afx_msg BSTR GetLinkInformation();
    afx_msg void SetLinkInformation(LPCTSTR lpszNewValue);
    afx_msg BSTR GetHelpMessage();
    afx_msg void SetHelpMessage(LPCTSTR lpszNewValue);
    afx_msg short GetLeft();
    afx_msg void SetLeft(short nNewValue);
    afx_msg short GetTop();
    afx_msg void SetTop(short nNewValue);
    afx_msg short GetInitSelect();
    afx_msg void SetInitSelect(short nNewValue);
    afx_msg short InitAccCombo(LPCTSTR strInitValue);
    afx_msg void EditFullCaption(LPCTSTR strCaption);
    afx_msg void ResetContent();
    afx_msg short AddRow(LPCTSTR strAccount);
    afx_msg short InsertRow(LPCTSTR strAccount, short iIndex);
    afx_msg void DeleteRow(short iIndex);
    afx_msg short GetCurSel();
    afx_msg void SetCurSel(short iIndex);
    afx_msg BSTR GetFirstCode();
    afx_msg BSTR GetMidCode();
    afx_msg short GetTotalRow();
    afx_msg void Sort(short bSortFlag);
    afx_msg void SetFocus();
    afx_msg BOOL UpdateFromMemory(const VARIANT FAR& DataArray);
    afx_msg BSTR GetAccountByIndex( short iIndex );
    afx_msg BOOL IsSupportedAgreementAccount(LPCTSTR    lpszAccount, long nAgreement);
    afx_msg void SetTotalTradeAccountDisplayFlag(BOOL bIsDisplay);
    afx_msg void IsLoadAllAccounts(BOOL bIsLoadAllAccounts);
    afx_msg long GetAccountCtrlType(void);
    afx_msg void SetAccountCtrlType(long lCtrlType);
    afx_msg BOOL GetReadOnly();
    afx_msg void SetReadOnly(BOOL bReadOnly);
    
    afx_msg BSTR GetProductCode();
    afx_msg BSTR GetBranchCode();
    afx_msg BOOL SetMSRHeaderClear();
    afx_msg short GetAccIsCmsn(LPCTSTR strAccount);

    //}}AFX_DISPATCH
    DECLARE_DISPATCH_MAP()
    DECLARE_INTERFACE_MAP()

public:
    enum
    {
    //{{AFX_DISP_ID(CDispatchAccount)
    dispidBranchCodeHide = 1L,
    dispidBorder = 2L,
    dispidBranchCodeAuto = 3L,
    dispidItemCodeDefault = 4L,
    dispidInputDevice = 5L,
    dispidItemCodeType = 6L,
    dispidAccNameCtl = 7L,
    dispidAccPwdCtl = 8L,
    dispidAddTrustAccount = 9L,
    dispidAutoNextFocus = 10L,
    dispidUseHistory = 11L,
    dispidRequireInput = 12L,
    dispidLeft = 13L,
    dispidTop = 14L,
    dispidHeight = 15L,
    dispidWidth = 16L,
    dispidEnabled = 17L,
    dispidVisible = 18L,
    dispidCaption = 19L,
    dispidBackColor = 20L,
    dispidForeColor = 21L,
    dispidLinkInformation = 22L,
    dispidHelpMessage = 23L,
    dispidInitSelect = 24L,
    dispidReadOnly = 50L,

    dispidInitAccCombo = 25L,
    dispidEditFullCaption = 26L,
    dispidResetContent = 27L,
    dispidAddRow = 28L,
    dispidInsertRow = 29L,
    dispidDeleteRow = 30L,
    dispidGetCurSel = 31L,
    dispidSetCurSel = 32L,
    dispidGetFirstCode = 33L,
    dispidGetMidCode = 34L,
    dispidGetTotalRow = 35L,
    dispidSort = 36L,
    dispidSetFocus = 37L,
    dispidUpdateFromMemory = 38L,
    dispidGetAccountByIndex = 39L,

    dispidIsSupportedAgreementAccount = 40L,
    dispidSetTotalTradeAccountDisplayFlag = 41L,
    dispidIsLoadAllAccounts = 42L,
    dispidGetAccountCtrlType = 43L,
    dispidSetAccountCtrlType = 44L,

    dispidGetProductCode = 45L,
    dispidGetBranchCode = 46L,
    dispidSetMSRHeaderClear = 47L,
    dispidGetAccIsCmsn = 48L,


    eventidSetFocus = 1L,
    eventidKillFocus = 2L,
    eventidTab = 3L,
    eventidEditFull = 4L,
    eventidEditEnter = 5L,
    eventidListSelChanged = 6L,
    eventidChangeAccount = 7L,
    eventidDropDown = 8L,
    eventidMSRReceived = 9L,
    eventidEmplEditFull = 10L,
    //}}AFX_DISP_ID
    };

    // Event maps
    //{{AFX_EVENT(CDispatchAccount)
    void FireSetFocus()
        {FireEvent(eventidSetFocus,EVENT_PARAM(VTS_NONE));}
    void FireKillFocus()
        {FireEvent(eventidKillFocus,EVENT_PARAM(VTS_NONE));}
    void FireTab()
        {FireEvent(eventidTab,EVENT_PARAM(VTS_NONE));}
    void FireEditFull()
        {FireEvent(eventidEditFull,EVENT_PARAM(VTS_NONE));}
    void FireEditEnter()
        {FireEvent(eventidEditEnter,EVENT_PARAM(VTS_NONE));}
    void FireListSelChanged(short iIndex)
        {FireEvent(eventidListSelChanged,EVENT_PARAM(VTS_I2), iIndex);}
    void FireChangeAccount()
        {FireEvent(eventidChangeAccount,EVENT_PARAM(VTS_NONE));}
    void FireDropDown(short bListShow)
        {FireEvent(eventidDropDown,EVENT_PARAM(VTS_I2), bListShow);}
    void FireMSRReceived(LPCTSTR    lpszAccount, BOOL bIsOldWooriCard, VARIANT FAR* pvarCancelFlag)
        {FireEvent(eventidMSRReceived,EVENT_PARAM(VTS_BSTR VTS_BOOL VTS_PVARIANT), lpszAccount, bIsOldWooriCard, pvarCancelFlag);}
    void FireEmplEditFull()
        {FireEvent(eventidEmplEditFull,EVENT_PARAM(VTS_NONE));}
    //}}AFX_EVENT

    DECLARE_EVENT_MAP()

};
```

I try to change to static void and still i am getting this error

i don't know what cause this error, cause in VC++6.0 succeed compile without error
And the error is indicated on the BEGIN_EVENT_MAP line.

I have searched around and can't figure it out. Is there anybody who did such thing ? Or am i going wrong with this code

Thank you

PS: sorry for my english

Comment: can you figure out what this is defined as? `__CMDTARGET_API` Can you try taking that out of your class definition and see what happens?

Comment: What's `CDispatchAccount`?

Comment: _CMDTARGET_API defined as :  #if _CONTROL_DLL 
                                               #define __CMDTARGET_API  __declspec(dllimport)
                                            #endif    
also i try to taking out that class, and give me undefined error

Comment: Are you trying to convert this to 64bit?

Comment: no, i not convert to 64 bit, i just doing it on 32 bit

Comment: @Nazz please put all relevant information __into__ the question. You can [edit]  your question.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. The link contains instructions on how to derive one. Make sure to meet both of these requirements: minimal *and* complete.

Comment: That's not a [mcve]. Make it **minimal**.